# Chrome Internal Certificate Authority List for SSL + EV

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, tls-intercept

Chrome specifies that it maintains a internal "hard-coded" list of root certificates that are "EV-Qualified".

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy#TOC-Extended-Validation-Certificates

Is there any up-to-date list of these certificates that is publicly available?

To be totally clear - This question pertains **specifically** to **Extended Validation Certificates** I understand that we can manipulate our trusted certificates for non EV.

Also, has anyone experienced what happens when Chrome encounters an EV cert which has a user-defined trusted root which is not in the "hard-coded" list?  I'm wondering how this would work behind a "SSL-Inspecting" security device.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily find them in the source code of Chromium:

[ev_root_ca_metadata.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/cert/ev_root_ca_metadata.cc?sq=package:chromium)

If the EV Root Certificate isn't in that list it will simply be used like any other root certificate, i.e. no fancy name company name in the address bar.

Comment: Welcome to security.se! To make your answer a little more self-contained, can you also answer the last paragraph of the question?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth, done.